# Не работает код Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    double d = scan.nextDouble();
    String s = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    scan.close();
}
```

}

Помогите найти ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Comment: `Double` десятичную часть разделяйте `,`, а не  `.`

Comment: @azlov, строку не хочет читать даже

Comment: строка как раз была прочтена: символ перевода строки, когда вы вводили значение `double`. как решение - добавьте `scan.nextLine();` перед считыванием строки `String s = scan.nextLine();`

Comment: @azlov спасибо, помогло